# Akka.net: Child per entity pattern in a cluster

Tags: akka.net, akka.net-cluster

We are developing a project to process finantial transactions. We would like to have a "distributed memory" accross three machines where these transactions live. All machines would have their own copy of a transaction as a transaction update request could arrive to any of those machines.

We were thinking about using Akka.net cluster to try to resolve this problem. Is there a way to use the child per entity pattern (all transactions are accessed by their own transaction id and we want that the transaction actor doesn't have to load anything from disk) in an Akka cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think cluster sharding can help as you can create shards per entity. https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-sharding.html